# Start cmd.exe with echo off on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I would like to know how to start a cmd.exe window with echo already turn off. For example, I have the following Command line :

```
start cmd /k test.exe
```

which start `test.exe` in a new cmd window. But in this cmd window, echo is on.

Is it possible to start `test.exe`in a new cmd window where echo is off ?

Comment: The echo state only affects batch files, and you're running an executable, so I think this is an XY problem.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 5):

```
> cmd /?
...
/Q      Turns echo off
...
```

So this should do the trick:

```
start cmd /q /k test.exe
```

Comment: For me, /Q means "Execute the given command then remain active" (translation of French Windows CMD). I am on Windows 7 also.

Comment: That's /K on my version: "Carries out the command specified by string but remains".

Comment: @LucasWillems - Huh? Are you sure? I've never heard of the meaning of command switches changing with language.

Comment: from help Win7 german: `/k` execute and remain open, `/q` turn off echo

Comment: @LucasWillems, the "(sans interactions)" part is missing from your translation which is the "echo off" in french I believe.

Comment: @RealHowTo, Ok but when I had /q, CMD still starts with echo on.

Comment: @LucasWillems ... sorry but /Q is working fine here (W7-fr). Maybe a screenshot of what you consider "echo is on" will help.